# Merging Two CSV Files Using Spacy nlp

Tags: python, csv, merge, nlp, spacy

I have two CSV files. They have a same column but each of rows in the same column are not unique, like this:

```
gpo_full.csv:
    Date           hearing_sub_type   topic      Specific_Date
    January,1997   Oversight          weather    January 12,1997
    June,2000      General            life       June 5,2000
    January,1997   General            forest     January 1,1997
    April,2001     Oversight          people     NaN 
    June,2000      Oversight          depressed  June 6,2000
    January,1997   General            weather    January 1,1997
    June,2000      Oversight          depressed  June 5,2000

CAP_cols.csv:
    majortopic   id     Chamber   topic           Date           Specific_Date
    21           79846  1         many forest     January,1997   January 1,1997
    4            79847  2         emotion         June,2000      June 6,2000
    13           79848  1         NaN             May,2001       NaN
    7            79849  2         good life       June,2000      June 5,2000
    21           79850  1         windy           January,1997   January 1,1997
    25           79851  1         rain & cloudy   January,1997   January 12,1997
    6            79852  2         sad & depressed June,2000      June 5,2000
```

I want to use three criteria to match these data: Specific_Date, Date, and topic. 
First, I want to use "Date" column to group these data. Next, I try to use "Specific_Date" column to narrow down the scope since some data are lost in this column. Finally, I want to use "topic" column by similar words like Spacy and nlp to make sure which rows in gpo_full can be corresponding with a unique row in CAP_cols. 
I have tried to use "Date" column to group the data and merge them into JSON file. However, I am trapped in achieving the next step to narrow down the scope by specific date and topic. 
My thought for this output would be like:

```
{
"Date": "January,1997",
"Specific_Date": "January 12,1997"
"similarity": 0.9
"GPO": {
    "hearing_sub_type": "Oversight",
    and other columns
}
"CAP": {
    "majortopic": "25",
    "id": "79851",
    "Chamber": "1"
}
},
{
"Date": "January,1997",
"Specific_Date": "January 1,1997"
"similarity": 0.89
"GPO": {
    "hearing_sub_type": "General",
    and other columns
}
"CAP": {
    "majortopic": "21",
    "id": "79846",
    "Chamber": "1"
}
and similar for others}
```

My specific question is how to use spacy to calculate similarity within the same date and to match the most similar row.\

My code I wrote is:

```
from pprint import pprint
import spacy

with open('gpo_full.csv') as gpo_file:
    gpo_reader = csv.DictReader(gpo_file)
    
    output = {}
    for gpo_row in gpo_reader:
        date = gpo_row["Date"]
        held_date = gpo_row["held_date"]
        
        if date not in output:
            output[date] = {"Date": date, "Specific_Date": held_date, "Similarity": [], "GPO": [], "CAP": []}
        
        output_gpo = [gpo_row["title"]]
        for sentence_gpo in output_gpo:
            gpo = nlp(sentence_gpo)
            
            with open("cap_colsNew.csv") as cap_file:
                cap_reader = csv.DictReader(cap_file)
                    
                for cap_row in cap_reader:
                    if date == cap_row["Date"]:
                        del cap_row["Date"]
                    if held_date == cap_row["held_date"]:
                        del cap_row["held_date"]
                        
                    output_cap = [cap_row["description"]] 
                    for sentence_cap in output_cap:
                        cap = nlp(sentence_cap)
                        
                        if gpo.similarity(cap) > 0.8:
                            output[date]["Similarity"].append(gpo.similarity(cap))
                            
                            output[date]["CAP"].append(cap_row)
                    
            if not output[date]["CAP"]:
                cap_row = {fieldname: None for fieldname in gpo_reader.fieldnames
                          if fieldname != "Date"}
                output[date]["CAP"].append(cap_row)
        
        if date in output:
            del gpo_row["Date"]
            if gpo.similarity(cap) > 0.8:
                output[date]["GPO"].append(gpo_row)
                
output = output.values()
pprint(output, sort_dicts = 0)
```

Could any find out the problem of my code? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `gpo_full.csv` CSV file in your question does not match the code in several ways. First of all the file looks tab-delimited, yet you open it with `csv.DictReader(gpo_file)` which would only work with one that was comma-delimited. More significantly, it doesn't contain `gpo_row["held_date"]` and `gpo_row["title"]` columns.

Comment: You should look into "deduplication" or "record linking". spaCy is not really the right tool for this. For topic matching it might be helpful, but for dates it's not what you want.

Comment: In addition to the discrepancies I already mentioned, your code is also reading a file named `"cap_colsNew.csv"`, *not* one named `CAP_cols.csv` as the one shown near the beginning is named. The sample file also doesn't contain some columns being referenced in the code, i.e. `cap_row["held_date"]` and `cap_row["description"]`.

Comment: I am sorry for posting these similar questions! I was trying to find out an effective way to solve this complex matching question. I was also trying to figure out this step by step, but the actual problem I want to solve is narrowing down the scope by date and matching them by topic through Spacy or other useful tools. But, it seems my idea is not feasible. So, I am looking for other ways and thus posting many similar questions.

Comment: I think I understand—the matching *is* complex. Here's a thought: If you could somehow extract the most significant topic keywords, then maybe you could narrow things down by performing [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) operations on groups of them, such as determining which have the most keywords in common (i.e. set intersection).